# Ruby: Index as param in array map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following hash keys

```
variable = { "Key1" => ["value1","value2"],
             "Key2" => ["value3","value4"]}
```

I need to iterate through each values of the key with index and print the first **deconstructed parameter**.

I tried

```
variable.
 values.
 map.
 with_index{|param1, param2, index|
     puts param1
 }
```

which gives me the output of

```
["value1", "value2"] 
["value3", "value4"]
```

My question is: Why is it printing the full value object?

I just need to get

```
"value1" 
"value3"
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: I need to map each param in the "map" with a variable name, which I was not able do it array

Comment: I'm a little bit confused on what you are asking. You only want the first element of the first key?

Comment: No I want first element of all keys with index

Comment: Could you give some extra test cases?

Comment: As result I would be requiring "value1", "value2", 1 for first hash and "value1", "value2", 2 for second hash

Comment: Your code doesn't work at all, since `variable` doesn't have a `values` method. So you don't get what you claim to get.

Comment: @JagdshLK Please edit your question and clarify. From your comments I see that you want some index, too. Also fix your code example (variable.values does not work ...). Please update your question and state the _exact_ result you wish to get. We might have language barriers here and there, but if you write in ruby we'll get it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `variable` is actually just a hash, since that fits the code you're running and the results you're seeing the best, if not this answer needs some slight modification, but should as whole still be relevant

```
variable = { "Key1" => ["value1", "value2"], "Key2" => ["value1", "value2"] }
```

---

Usually when you call `map`, the element being passed in, where applicable can be deconstructed:

```
variable.values.map { |p1, p2| puts p1 }
# value1
# value1
```

However, when you call `with_index` on it, it changes the behavior so that the first parameter passed is the element in your Enumerable, and the second is the index:

```
variable.values.map.with_index { |p1, p2| puts p1.inspect }
# ["value1", "value2"]
# ["value1", "value2"]
```

So, since things get ambiguous if you start trying to deconstruct multiple parameters (for instance, what if that second item, which in this case is an integer index was actually another array; what parameter goes with what array; similarly if your first parameter had 5 elements and you supply 3 parameters to the block, what should the interpreter think you meant to be doing?), you need to use a special syntax. You simply need to wrap the parameter names that should go with the first element in parenthesis:

```
variable.values.map.with_index do |(param1, param2), index|
  puts "p1: #{param1}; p2: #{param2}; index: #{index}"
end
# p1: value1; p2: value2; index: 0
# p1: value1; p2: value2; index: 1
```

and finally, if you are only interested in the first element of each value array, you can just assign the rest of the array to an unused variable, for instance:

```
variable.values.map.with_index do |(param1, *), index|
  puts "p1: #{param1}; index: #{index}"
end
# p1: value1; index: 0
# p1: value1; index: 1
```

And naturally, since this isn't actually mapping the values to anything, this is all applicable to `each.with_index` as well.

Comment: if your `variable` was correct and the code you ran/output was wrong (the opposite of the assumption I made on this answer); you can run the above on `variable.map { |hash| hash.values.flatten }` or `variable.map { |hash| hash.values.first }` instead of `variable.values`

Comment: Thank you @simple lime. This is what I was trying to explain in my question but failed.